# How to display system date on the webpage in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to display the current locale system date in a jsf page. I'm having the below code but it's not working.

```
<p:column styleClass="columnA">SOP Date</p:column>
<p:column styleClass="columnB">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.currentDate}" />
</p:column>
```

The managed bean looks like code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
public class SopDate implements Serializable {

    public String currentDate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       SopCurrentDate();
    }

    public void SopCurrentDate(){
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.currentDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
      }
      // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not working` ?

Comment: i mean system date is not getting displayed on the webpage using above code.

Comment: @PostConstruct is not working?

Comment: Did you inspected the currentDate after the init method in your bean? Just for note, you should declare a property as `private` and use getters/setters to make it public, for security matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.currentDate}">
   <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="#{bean.format}" timeZone="(here your timezone)"/>
 </h:outputText>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class SopDate implements Serializable {

    public Date currentDate;
    public String format;  

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       SopCurrentDate();
    }

    public void SopCurrentDate(){
       currentDate = new Date(); 
       format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
      // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass a String Date, you can use Date property to show date.

Comment: date pattern should be taken from the browser setting.

Comment: When you can have another property in Bean, i will edit the answer.

Comment: The code I have pasted just added the sysout and its populating the system date in server log but not displaying in the web page.

Comment: Please add ViewScoped to Bean.

Comment: added the ViewScoped but facing the same issue.

Comment: I just tested this! That's work! All another jsf component works well?

Comment: @ Cesar Zegarra : Thanks for your time its working now, problem was something else.